# cannot convert PIL thumbnails to PYQt4 icons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-imaging-library

i have a problem when converting some Qimages to thumbnails using PIL.
 to be used in a list widget , check the image below

[image]

where the image should look like :

[image]

please note that i use horizontal flow and the text of item is an empty text 
one more thing :  **this only happens when i put more than 1 image**

```
for i in listOfImages:
    picture = Image.open(i)

    picture.thumbnail((50,50), Image.ANTIALIAS )
    qimage = QtGui.QImage(ImageQt.ImageQt(picture))
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimage))





    item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(str(path))

    item.setIcon(icon)

    self.listWidget.addItem(item)
```

any idea what is going on ? and why images are being pixlated ?.. any better solutions

EDIT : using

```
pix = QtGui.QPixmap(path)
pix = pix.scaled(50,50,QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
icon = QtGui.QIcon(pix)
```

will be very problematic (needed 10 seconds to run) while the code above needed 1 second.

thanks

Comment: Did this ever get resolved?  I'm having the same issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
from io import BytesIO
qimage = QtGui.QImage()
fp = BytesIO()
picture.save(fp, "BMP")
qimage.loadFromData(fp.getvalue(), "BMP")
```

icon ...

I had tried ImageQt, but the performance is not good. 
I reference http://doloopwhile.hatenablog.com/entry/20100305/1267782841
Because I use python 3.3, cStringIO is replaced by BytesIO

Answer (score 0):

I've not used PIL with PyQt. Have you tried using a [QImageReader](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qimagereader.html)?

```
    item = QListWidgetItem(image_path)

    imageReader = QImageReader()
    imageReader.setFileName(image_path)
    size = imageReader.size()
    size.scale(50, 50, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    imageReader.setScaledSize(size)
    image = imageReader.read()

    pix = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
    icon = QIcon(pix)
    item.setIcon(icon)
    self.listWidget.addItem(item)
```

Comment: TOO slow. needed 11 seconds to run ( used 30 images ) . i need it to be able to handle 10 times more than that.